# Brightness setting not working on Xubuntu 15.04 ( vivid vervet)

Tags: xubuntu, brightness, 15.04

I recently upgraded from xubuntu 14.04 to 14.10 and then to 15.04 on Lenovo z580. I used to control brightness on 14.04 using xbacklight from command line. Now its not working. 15.04 also has a brightness control option in power management plugin. This one also not working. How to troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: by control brightness, do you mean automatic brightness level on AC and Battery?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem in Ubuntu 15.04. This is how I solved it.
First use `ls /sys/class/backlight/` to see which video card is installed. In my case the above command showed `intel_backlight`. After this I did:

```
sudo touch /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf # create 20-intel.conf file`

sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf #open the file
```

and add the following lines to this file

```
Section "Device"
            Identifier  "card0"
            Driver      "intel"
            Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
            BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
    EndSection
```

save and exit. Log out and log-in back.

Try the following if the above did not work:

`sudo nano /etc/default/grub`

Make the line that say `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` to look like the following:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_backlight=vendor"`

Update grub by: `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

As a final option try this: `xrandr --output LVDS1 --brightness 0.8`. Play with numbers other than 0.8 and see what happens.

Comment: I tried that, but no change.

Comment: what does `ls /sys/class/backlight/` say?

Comment: intel_backlight

Comment: Can you please tell what does `cat /etc/default/grub | grep GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=` say too.

Comment: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""`

Comment: @neoFox try the alternate solution in my edited answer above.

Comment: I tried. It dint work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23293/discussion-between-ron-and-neofox).

Comment: worked for me on an acer aspire