# Please I am new to ubuntu 14.04 and i can't adjust my screen brightness

Tags: 14.04, brightness

Please I am new to ubuntu 14.04 and i can't adjust my screen brightness. I'm using HP Pro book-450-G2. but i dual boot the ubuntu with windows 10 and my brightness can be adjusted in windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

You can install xbacklight with `sudo apt-get install xbacklight`, and then try `xbacklight -set 10`.

If that does not work, then open up the folder `/sys/class/backlight/` and see if there are any entries. If not, then you probably don't have your video drivers installed.

Edit: OK, the following seems to have worked for OP: [Brightness setting not working on Xubuntu 15.04 ( vivid vervet)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615974/brightness-setting-not-working-on-xubuntu-15-04-vivid-vervet)

Comment: Please, i tried it and it didn't work, but there are entries in /sys/class/backlight.   the entries are acpi and intel.

Comment: @RichmondSelikemChris-Koka: Could you please see if <pre>tee /sys/class/backlight/intel/brightness <<< 5</pre> or <pre>tee /sys/class/backlight/acpi/brightness <<< 5</pre> works?

Comment: Please I tried the Brightness setting not working on Xubuntu 15.04 and it is now WORKING!!!!!!!!!. yaay. I'm so happy. thank you and God bless you.

Comment: Please i need one more thing.

Comment: I can't connect to wifi networks. I can only use an ethernet cable for internet connections. there's no option for me to even see available wifi

Comment: @RichmondSelikemChris-Koka: You could ask a separate question, but if you don't want to, could you please tell the output of `lspci | grep -i wireless`?

Comment: please this is the output : 09:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter   @mkdrive2

Comment: @RichmondSelikemChris-Koka: Are you using the standard Unity desktop of Ubuntu or a different one? If you are using Unity: At the upper right corner you should have something like this http://fs5.directupload.net/images/160213/o93bmdwt.png. After you have unplugged the ethernet cable, do you see the second symbol in the picture? Are you unable to configure wifi with it? What have you tried? Sorry, I cannot ask you these questions [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/733238/please-im-new-to-ubuntu-14-04-and-i-cant-connect-to-wifi), because I don't have enough rep, yet.