# Please I'm new to ubuntu 14.04 and i can't connect to wifi

Tags: wireless, intel-wireless

Please, i'm new to ubuntu 14.04 and i can't connect to wifi available. I'm using hp pro book 450-G2. But i can use an ethernet cable to connect to the internet. there's actually no option for me to see available WIFI connections.

```
09:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2231]_
```

Comment: Welcome! You'll need to provide some info about the wireless hardware. For example, open a terminal window, type `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 0280`, and hit Enter. Then edit the question, and add the output to it.

Comment: @mikewhatever . Done what you said i should do.

Comment: Thanks, here is what came up when I search for "RTL8723BE ubuntu": http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/ubuntu-trusty-realtek.html. Hope it helps.

Comment: @mikewhatever please it did'nt work. please can you give me another solution??

Comment: Sure, I'll search again, and post back if I find anything.

Comment: @Jeremy31 : Thanks Jeremy. I followed the instructions there and now i can connect to wifi. !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! yaay!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this workaround (not a fix):

After you boot the system, suspend and wake up. Now check if wifi
networks are detected or not.
I read this somewhere sometime ago, it works for my hp laptop.